# Ajax form submit without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I simply want to submit my form to the same page with ajax without page refresh. So my below code submits the form but $_POST values are not picked ... Am I submitting it properly. I don't get any error but I think my form is not submitting.

html form

```
<form action="" id="fixeddonation" name="fixeddonation" method="post">


<input type="hidden" class="donerProject" name="donerProject" value="test">
<input type="hidden" class="donersubProject" id="donersubProject" name="donersubProject" value="general">
<input type="hidden" class="donerLocations" id="donerLocations" name="donerLocations" value="general">

<input type="hidden" class="donationpagetype" name="donationpagetype" value="general">
<input type="hidden" class="projectadded" id="projectadded" name="projectadded" value="1">
<input type="hidden" value="302" id="pageid" name="pageid">
<div class="classsetrepet generalfixshow  fullrow row fixed-page">
<div class="col-6 text-right">      
<div class="prize">Fixed  Amount £</div>    
</div>
<div class="col-6"> 
<input type="text" id="oneoffamt" name="oneoffamt" class="oneoffamt validatenumber">
<span class="amt_error"></span>
</div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6"></div>
<div class="col-6">
<input type="submit" id="submit_gen_one" class="btn-block" value="submit" name="submit_gen_one">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Ajax code

```
jQuery('#fixeddonation').on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: jQuery('#fixeddonation').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                alert('form was submitted');
                jQuery('#collapse2').addClass('in').removeAttr('aria-expanded').removeAttr('style'); jQuery('#collapse1').removeClass('in').removeAttr('aria-expanded').removeAttr('style');

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a correct value to the action tag of your form and try this:

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {

 var form = $('#fixeddonation');

  form.submit(function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();


     var formData = form.serialize();
     $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url:  form.attr('action'),
        data:  formData
    }) .done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
  });
  });

}); // end .ready()

</script>
```

Don't need return false as you already called preventDefault() first thing

Comment: Maximo the form is set to refresh on the same page in wordpress so in that scenario what can I use in action field

Comment: Ok, the "action" require the correct path to the script that would process the form if ajax wouldn't prevent that. Where's the php script that processes the form? Is this the one? 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'

Comment: All right then, if it's the same page type this in: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>

Comment: please check I've written like this ... is it in correct now @Maximo url:  form.attr('<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>'),

Comment: No ! : ) You cannot type php into jquery. That was supposed to go into the html tag : <form action="" id="fixeddonation" name="fixeddonation" method="post">  . See up there? action is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127322/discussion-between-maximo-and-zeeshan).

Answer (score -1):

First create Template

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Test */

get_header();
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">
    <p class="register-message" style="display:none"></p>
      <form action="#" method="POST" name="testregister" class="register-form">
      <fieldset> 
          <label><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Register Form</label>

          <input type="text"  name="firstname" placeholder="Username" id="firstname">
          <p id="firstname-error" style="display:none">Firstname Must Be Enter</p>
          <input type="email"  name="email" placeholder="Email address" id="email">
          <p id="email-error" style="display:none">Email Must Be Enter</p>
          <input type="submit"  class="button" id="test" value="Register" >
      </fieldset>
    </form> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery('#test').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var firstname = jQuery('#firstname').val();
        var email = jQuery('#email').val();
         if (firstname == "") {
             jQuery('#firstname-error').show();
            return false;
        } else {
            jQuery('#firstname-error').hide();

        }
        if (email == "") {   jQuery('#email-error').show();     return false;   } 
        else { jQuery('#email-error').hide();   }

        jQuery.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
          data: {
            action: "test",
            firstname : firstname,
            email : email
          },
          success: function(results){
            console.log(results);
            jQuery('.register-message').text(results).show();
          },
          error: function(results) {

          }
        });
      });
    </script>


        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

after that create a function (function.php in wordpress)

```
add_action('wp_ajax_test', 'test', 0);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test', 'test');
function test() {
      $firstname = stripcslashes($_POST['firstname']);
      $email = stripcslashes($_POST['email']);

       global $wpdb;

    $q = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_test WHERE email='".$email."' ");
    $res = $wpdb->get_results($q);
   if(count($res)>0)
   {
       echo "Email Allready Register ";
   }
    else
    {
      $user_data = array(
          'firstname' => $firstname,
          'email' => $email
        );
         $tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'test'; // if use wordpress
         $user_id= $wpdb->insert( $tablename,$user_data );
         echo 'we have Created an account for you';
    die;
    }
}
```